# WSDL element is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, nullreferenceexception

I have an WSDL document and it has elements like this above.

```
  <s:element name="NewPortalOrder">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderType" type="tns:CardSalesType" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Customer" type="tns:PortalCustomerContainer" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="InvoiceAddress" type="tns:AddressContainer" />
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DeliveryAddress" type="tns:AddressContainer" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Cards" type="tns:ArrayOfPortalCardContainer" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

I added the WSDL file as a ServiceReference into the solution.

On the server side

```
  WS.NewPortalOrderRequest order = new WS.NewPortalOrderRequest();

  order.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine1 = txtAddress.Text;
  order.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine2 = txtAddress2.Text;
```

On the `order.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine1 = txtAddress.Text;` line I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

When I watch the `order.InvoiceAddress`, I see that is null. Why can I get this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: How are you creating `order.InvoiceAdress`?  Can you show the complete code?

Comment: I added it into the question @Tim

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you need to create an instance of `InvoiceAddress` in the `NewPortalOrderRequest`, like this:

```
WS.NewPortalOrderRequest order = new WS.NewPortalOrderRequest();

order.InvoiceAddress = new WS.InvoiceAddress();

// Now you can assign values to InvoiceAddress' property:
order.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine1 = txtAddress.Text;
order.InvoiceAddress.AddressLine2 = txtAddress2.Text;
```

You might need to do `order.InvoiceAddress = new WS.AddressContainer()` based on the WSDL, but I'm not 100% sure on that one.

Comment: When I do order.InvoiceAddress = new WS.AddressContainer(); it works corretly. Thanks!